# How to embed a website within ipython notebook

Tags: python, url, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I want to make my notebook such that a website open within notebook and anything I do/click in website, it works like it open in new tab but remains within ipython notebook cell only. I know about selenium package which open the website in new tab or there are other ways to0 but every time, I need to leave notebook and go to either new window/tab. So how can I make my ipython notebook such that it open website within cell and whatever I do, it remains within notebook. Thanks

Comment: There is [`IPython.display.HTML`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html?highlight=HTML#IPython.display.HTML) which you can use like `HTML(url='https://www.google.com/')`. But it has some problems with displaying, and you can't properly navigate there.

Comment: @Georgy: Thanks. I tried this. Google is working almost fine except doodle (not loading properly) but when I am trying `HTML(url='http://www.mirnet.ca/')`. This website is not working well.

Comment: You also could use [`%%html`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-html) magic command like: `%%html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" width="400" height="300"></iframe>`, but not all the websites allow embedding in iframes. Maybe there are other options though.

Comment: @Georgy  : I am getting usage error : `UsageError: %%html is a cell magic, but the cell body is empty.`

Comment: After `%%html` on the next line in the same cell add `<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" width="400" height="300"></iframe>`. It should work.

Comment: I am wondering if it allows an iframe in a markdown cell.

Answer (score 25):

You can try this:

```
%%html
<iframe src="https://playground.tensorflow.org" width="1200" height="1000"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

For sites that can be embedded in IFrame, you can try

```
from IPython.display import IFrame
IFrame("https://www.openasapp.com/embedding-an-iframe-step-by-step/", 900,500)
```

This will work if IFrame() is the last thing called in the cell becuase Jupyter Notebooks automatically call the display function on the last active line in the cell. If you want to have this at the beginning of the cell, you will need to call display manually like this

```
from IPython.display import IFrame
display(IFrame("https://www.openasapp.com/embedding-an-iframe-step-by-step/", 900,500))

print("This code is now the last line, so we need to call display(Iframe()) explicitly")
```